# Unable to send the published message to the subscriber in open62541

Tags: linux, publish-subscribe, opc-ua, open62541

I am trying to build learn the open62541, I am using the sample example [Here](https://github.com/open62541/open62541/blob/master/examples/pubsub/tutorial_pubsub_publish.c).

I saved the example as publish.c
and compiled with cmake options,
cmake -DUA_ENABLE_SUBSCRIPTIONS=ON -DUA_ARCHITECTURE=freertosLWIP -DUA_ENABLE_AMALGAMATION=ON -DUA_ENABLE_PUBSUB=ON -DUA_ENABLE_PUBSUB_ETH_UADP=ON ../
After compiling the example
I get below error :

```
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.328 (UTC+0100)] warn/server AccessControl: Unconfigured AccessControl. Users have all permissions.
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.328 (UTC+0100)] info/server AccessControl: Anonymous login is enabled
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.328 (UTC+0100)] warn/server Username/Password configured, but no encrypting SecurityPolicy. This can leak credentials on the network.
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.328 (UTC+0100)] warn/userland AcceptAll Certificate Verification. Any remote certificate will be accepted.
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.328 (UTC+0100)] info/userland PubSub channel requested
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.328 (UTC+0100)] info/network TCP network layer listening on opc.tcp://gaurav-VirtualBox:4840
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.431 (UTC+0100)] warn/server PubSub Connection sending failed.
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.431 (UTC+0100)] error/server PubSub Publish: Could not send a NetworkMessage
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.528 (UTC+0100)] warn/server PubSub Connection sending failed.
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.528 (UTC+0100)] error/server PubSub Publish: Could not send a NetworkMessage
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.631 (UTC+0100)] warn/server PubSub Connection sending failed.
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.631 (UTC+0100)] error/server PubSub Publish: Could not send a NetworkMessage
**[2021-02-10 21:15:41.729 (UTC+0100)] warn/server PubSub Connection sending failed.
[2021-02-10 21:15:41.729 (UTC+0100)] error/server PubSub Publish: Could not send a NetworkMessage**
```

I changed the publishing interval to 1 sec.
So after every 1 second, the published sends out the message but somehow I am getting this error :

```
**PubSub Connection sending failed. & error/server PubSub Publish: Could not send a NetworkMessage**
```

continuously until ctrl-c is pressed.

Can anyone help me to get this working on my pc

The code looks like this

```
    #include "OPCUA/open62541.h"
    #include "OPCUA/opcua.h"

    UA_NodeId connectionIdent, publishedDataSetIdent, writerGroupIdent, 
    dataSetWriterIdent;
    UA_NodeId connectionIdentifier;
    UA_PublishedDataSetConfig publishedDataSetConfig;
    UA_DataSetWriterConfig dataSetWriterConfig;
    UA_Boolean running = true;



     static void
     addPubSubConnection(UA_Server *server, UA_String *transportProfile,
                    UA_NetworkAddressUrlDataType *networkAddressUrl){
    /* Details about the connection configuration and handling are located
     * in the pubsub connection tutorial */
    UA_PubSubConnectionConfig connectionConfig;
    memset(&connectionConfig, 0, sizeof(connectionConfig));
    connectionConfig.name = UA_STRING("UADP Connection 1");
    connectionConfig.transportProfileUri = *transportProfile;
    connectionConfig.enabled = UA_TRUE;
    UA_Variant_setScalar(&connectionConfig.address, networkAddressUrl,
                         &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_NETWORKADDRESSURLDATATYPE]);


    /* Changed to static publisherId from random generation to identify
     * the publisher on Subscriber side */
    connectionConfig.publisherId.numeric = UA_UInt32_random();
    UA_KeyValuePair connectionOptions[3];

        connectionOptions[0].key = UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(0, "ttl");
        UA_UInt32 ttl = 10;
        UA_Variant_setScalar(&connectionOptions[0].value, &ttl,
                &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_UINT32]);

        connectionOptions[1].key = UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(0, "loopback");
        UA_Boolean loopback = UA_FALSE;
        UA_Variant_setScalar(&connectionOptions[1].value, &loopback,
                &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_BOOLEAN]);

        connectionOptions[2].key = UA_QUALIFIEDNAME(0, "reuse");
        UA_Boolean reuse = UA_TRUE;
        UA_Variant_setScalar(&connectionOptions[2].value, &reuse,
                &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_BOOLEAN]);

        connectionConfig.connectionProperties = connectionOptions;
        connectionConfig.connectionPropertiesSize = 3;
    UA_StatusCode retval = UA_Server_addPubSubConnection(server, &connectionConfig, &connectionIdent);
    if (retval == UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD) {
      UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_SERVER,
                                   "1 --> The PubSub Connection was added successfully!");
      }
    printf("networkAddressUrl.url                                   : %s \n", networkAddressUrl->url.data);
    printf ("Done addPubSubConnection here...\r\n");
}
     static void
     addPublishedDataSet(UA_Server *server) {
    /* The PublishedDataSetConfig contains all necessary public
    * informations for the creation of a new PublishedDataSet */
    UA_PublishedDataSetConfig publishedDataSetConfig;
    memset(&publishedDataSetConfig, 0, sizeof(UA_PublishedDataSetConfig));
    publishedDataSetConfig.publishedDataSetType = UA_PUBSUB_DATASET_PUBLISHEDITEMS;
    publishedDataSetConfig.name = UA_STRING("Demo PDS");
    /* Create new PublishedDataSet based on the PublishedDataSetConfig. */
    UA_AddPublishedDataSetResult result = UA_Server_addPublishedDataSet(server, &publishedDataSetConfig, &publishedDataSetIdent);
    if (result.addResult == UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD){
        UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_SERVER,
                                          "2 -->The addPublishedDataSet was created successfully!");
    }
        printf ("Done addPublishedDataSet here...\r\n");
}

static void
addDataSetField(UA_Server *server) {
    /* Add a field to the previous created PublishedDataSet */
    UA_NodeId dataSetFieldIdent;
    UA_DataSetFieldConfig dataSetFieldConfig;
    memset(&dataSetFieldConfig, 0, sizeof(UA_DataSetFieldConfig));
    dataSetFieldConfig.dataSetFieldType = UA_PUBSUB_DATASETFIELD_VARIABLE;
    dataSetFieldConfig.field.variable.fieldNameAlias = UA_STRING("Server localtime");
    dataSetFieldConfig.field.variable.promotedField = UA_FALSE;
    dataSetFieldConfig.field.variable.publishParameters.publishedVariable =
    UA_NODEID_NUMERIC(0, UA_NS0ID_SERVER_SERVERSTATUS_CURRENTTIME);
    dataSetFieldConfig.field.variable.publishParameters.attributeId = UA_ATTRIBUTEID_VALUE;
    UA_DataSetFieldResult result = UA_Server_addDataSetField(server, publishedDataSetIdent,
                              &dataSetFieldConfig, &dataSetFieldIdent);
    if (result.result == UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD)
    {
        UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_SERVER,
                                       "3--> The PubSub UA_Server_addDataSetField successfully!");
    }
    printf ("Done addDataSetField here...\r\n");
}

static void
addWriterGroup(UA_Server *server) {
    /* Now we create a new WriterGroupConfig and add the group to the existing
     * PubSubConnection. */
    UA_WriterGroupConfig writerGroupConfig;
    memset(&writerGroupConfig, 0, sizeof(UA_WriterGroupConfig));
    writerGroupConfig.name = UA_STRING("Demo WriterGroup");
    writerGroupConfig.publishingInterval = 1000;
    writerGroupConfig.enabled = UA_FALSE;
    writerGroupConfig.writerGroupId = 2234;
    writerGroupConfig.encodingMimeType = UA_PUBSUB_ENCODING_UADP;
    writerGroupConfig.messageSettings.encoding = UA_EXTENSIONOBJECT_DECODED;
    writerGroupConfig.messageSettings.content.decoded.type = &UA_TYPES[UA_TYPES_UADPWRITERGROUPMESSAGEDATATYPE];
    /* The configuration flags for the messages are encapsulated inside the
     * message- and transport settings extension objects. These extension
     * objects are defined by the standard. e.g.
     * UadpWriterGroupMessageDataType */
    UA_UadpWriterGroupMessageDataType *writerGroupMessage  = UA_UadpWriterGroupMessageDataType_new();
    /* Change message settings of writerGroup to send PublisherId,
     * WriterGroupId in GroupHeader and DataSetWriterId in PayloadHeader
     * of NetworkMessage */
    writerGroupMessage->networkMessageContentMask          = (UA_UadpNetworkMessageContentMask)(UA_UADPNETWORKMESSAGECONTENTMASK_PUBLISHERID |
                                                              (UA_UadpNetworkMessageContentMask)UA_UADPNETWORKMESSAGECONTENTMASK_GROUPHEADER |
                                                              (UA_UadpNetworkMessageContentMask)UA_UADPNETWORKMESSAGECONTENTMASK_WRITERGROUPID |
                                                              (UA_UadpNetworkMessageContentMask)UA_UADPNETWORKMESSAGECONTENTMASK_PAYLOADHEADER);
    writerGroupConfig.messageSettings.content.decoded.data = writerGroupMessage;
    UA_StatusCode retval1 = UA_Server_addWriterGroup(server, connectionIdent, &writerGroupConfig, &writerGroupIdent);
    if (retval1 == UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD )
    {
        UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_SERVER,
                                               "4-->The PubSub Connection UA_Server_addWriterGroup successfully!");
    }
    UA_StatusCode retval2 =  UA_Server_setWriterGroupOperational(server, writerGroupIdent);
    if (retval2 == UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD )
        {
            UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_SERVER,
                                                   "4.1-->The PubSub UA_Server_setWriterGroupOperational executed successfully!");
        }
    UA_UadpWriterGroupMessageDataType_delete(writerGroupMessage);

    printf("Done addWriterGroup here...\r\n");
}

static void
addDataSetWriter(UA_Server *server) {
    /* We need now a DataSetWriter within the WriterGroup. This means we must
     * create a new DataSetWriterConfig and add call the addWriterGroup function. */
    UA_NodeId dataSetWriterIdent;
    UA_DataSetWriterConfig dataSetWriterConfig;
    memset(&dataSetWriterConfig, 0, sizeof(UA_DataSetWriterConfig));
    dataSetWriterConfig.name = UA_STRING("Demo DataSetWriter");
    dataSetWriterConfig.dataSetWriterId = 62541;
    dataSetWriterConfig.keyFrameCount = 10;
    UA_StatusCode retval =  UA_Server_addDataSetWriter(server, writerGroupIdent, publishedDataSetIdent,
                               &dataSetWriterConfig, &dataSetWriterIdent);
    if (retval == UA_STATUSCODE_GOOD)
    {
        UA_LOG_INFO(UA_Log_Stdout, UA_LOGCATEGORY_SERVER,
                      "5-->The PubSub addDataSetWriter executed successfully!");
    }
    printf("Done addDataSetWriter here...\r\n");
}


    static int opcua_call (UA_String *transportProfile,
        UA_NetworkAddressUrlDataType *networkAddressUrl)
{
    UA_Boolean running = true;
    /* Create the Server */
    UA_Server *server = UA_Server_new();
    if (server != 0)
        printf("Server Created Successfully...\r\n");
    else
        printf("Failed to create Server...\r\n");

    UA_ServerConfig *config = UA_Server_getConfig(server);
    UA_ServerConfig_setDefault(config);
        /* Server is created now */

    /* Add the PubSubTransportLayer implementation to the server config.
     * The PubSubTransportLayer is a factory to create new connections
     * on runtime. The UA_PubSubTransportLayer is used for all kinds of
     * concrete connections e.g. UDP, MQTT, AMQP...
     */
    UA_String hostname;
    hostname = UA_STRING("opc.udp://224.0.0.21");
    UA_ServerConfig_setCustomHostname(UA_Server_getConfig(server), hostname);


    wiced_hostname_t whn;
    wiced_result_t wres;
    memset(&whn, 0, sizeof(whn));
    wiced_network_set_hostname("myServer");
    wres = wiced_network_get_hostname( &whn );
    printf ("wiced_network_get_hostname returned %d\n", wres);
    printf ("wiced_network_get_hostname: %s\n",whn.value );

/* Change the host name */
//            UA_String hostname;
//            UA_String_init(&hostname);
//            hostname.length = 8;
//            hostname.data =   "myServer";// "opc.udp://224.0.0.23:4841/"; //224.0.0.22:4840
//            printf ("Hostname is set with %s...\r\n", hostname.data);
//            UA_ServerConfig_setCustomHostname(UA_Server_getConfig(server), hostname);


    config->pubsubTransportLayers = (UA_PubSubTransportLayer *) UA_calloc(
            2, sizeof(UA_PubSubTransportLayer));

    config->pubsubTransportLayers[0] = UA_PubSubTransportLayerUDPMP();
    config->pubsubTransportLayersSize++;

       UA_PubSubConnectionConfig connectionConfig;
       memset(&connectionConfig, 0, sizeof(connectionConfig));
       connectionConfig.name = UA_STRING("UDP-UADP Connection 1");
       connectionConfig.transportProfileUri = UA_STRING("http://opcfoundation.org/UA-Profile/Transport/pubsub-udp-uadp");
       connectionConfig.enabled = UA_TRUE;


    addPubSubConnection(server, transportProfile, networkAddressUrl);
    addPublishedDataSet(server);
    addDataSetField(server);
    addWriterGroup(server);
    addDataSetWriter(server);


    UA_Server_run_startup(server);
    if (!config->pubsubTransportLayers) {
        UA_Server_delete(server);
        return -1;
        printf("Error ! \r\n");
    } else
        printf("Success Adding the Transport Layer... \r\n");

   // UA_StatusCode retval = UA_Server_run(server, &running);

    UA_Server_delete(server);

}

int opcua_pub_thread (void *arg)
{
    /* Configure the transport profile and Network Address*/
    UA_String transportProfile =
                        UA_STRING("http://opcfoundation.org/UA-Profile/Transport/pubsub-udp-uadp");
    UA_NetworkAddressUrlDataType networkAddressUrl =
                        {UA_STRING_NULL , UA_STRING("opc.udp://224.0.0.22:4840/")};

    networkAddressUrl.networkInterface = UA_STRING("udp");
    networkAddressUrl.url = UA_STRING("opc.udp://224.0.0.22");
    /* Start the pubsub procedure*/
    return opcua_call(&transportProfile, &networkAddressUrl);
}

void opcua_pub_init(void)
{
     printf("OPCUA Thread Created...\r\n");
    /* Create the opcua sttarting point thread */
    sys_thread_new("OPCUA Start", opcua_pub_thread, NULL, 20000, WICED_DEFAULT_LIBRARY_PRIORITY);

}
```

Comment: Please include your code here in the question as a [mcve], not as a link to what you may be following (more or less?).

Comment: @Robert Thanks for pointing it out. I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

This might be a Firewall issue? Are you in a company? Try turning it off.
If this does not solve the case, try to change the broadcast address from 224.0.0.22 to 239.255.0.1
I faced this problem with TCL, and somehow changing the Broadcast address helps. Even though, it should not matter. Maybe someone has a explanation for this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).